# R data table : How to find unknown number of empty cells directly below a specific cell and fill them with numbered strings

Tags: r, datatable

I know how to find empty `cells` in a `data.table` in general, but this is a little trickier and I haven't quite figured out how to manage this.

Lets say I have a `data.table` which in `df[2,1]` contains my keyword string i need to target: "Smart triggered!" in this case.

The amount of smart triggers used by the user of the instrument can vary, but they result in 1 empty cell below `df[2,1]` for each trigger, and their name in the 2nd `column`

I'm looking for a way to figure out how many empty `cells` are directly below "Smart triggered!" and fill them sequentially with "Smart trigger 1", Smart trigger 2"... until we hit the first next `cell` in `column` 1 that contains something ('Instrument'). There are potential other empty cells further down in the table that I do not want to alter.

In this case my info files read into a `data.table` looking like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Trigger", "Smart Triggered!", "", "", "Instrument", "Beam", "Core speed", "Channel1", "Channel2", "Channel3", "Channel4", ""),
values = c("SWS", "", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "Demo", "5um", "2.2", "FWS", "SWS", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "x"))
```

I suspect perhaps a while loop, but there are probably better data table solutions than that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if this works for you:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(name = c("Trigger", "Smart Triggered!", "", "", "Instrument", "Beam", "Core speed", "Channel1", "Channel2", "Channel3", "Channel4", ""),
                 values = c("SWS", "", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "Demo", "5um", "2.2", "FWS", "SWS", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "x"))

df %>%
  mutate(new_name = ifelse(as.character(name) == "", NA, as.character(name))) %>%
  tidyr::fill(new_name) %>%
  split(.$new_name) %>%
  map_df(., ~.x %>% mutate(row_no = row_number(),
                           row_no = lag(row_no),
                           new_name1 = ifelse(is.na(row_no), 
                                              as.character(new_name), 
                                              paste0(as.character(new_name), "_", row_no)))) %>%
  select(name, new_name, new_name1, values) %>%
  full_join(df, .) %>%
  mutate(name = as.character(name)) %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(new_name == "Smart Triggered!", new_name1, name)) %>%
  select(name, values)
```

Comment: I like how this looks, but it does also affect the other empty cells I want to avoid, in the dummy for instance the cell next to 'x', and it changes the order of the rows

Comment: code updated. You could build into a function and cycle through the variable names you are interested in

Comment: very nice. Do you happen to know of any good reading material to learn more about using this type of coding? How did you learn to do this for instance

Comment: Welcome to the tidyverse! this is a good starting point <https://www.tidyverse.org/>. I can't remember a single source of learning. I do love this style of coding as I can come back to it after 6 months and easily figure out the logic flow

Comment: very cool, I will have a read on the weekend. I have one other scenario of the same tables, would you mind looking at it if I post it as a new question? or as edit scenario 2 underneath the current question

Comment: I sometimes get an error from the row_number() part inside map_df, saying: Warning: Error in : row_number() should only be called in a data context
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Any idea why? I can provide the input data if needed

Comment: could you try reinstalling `rlang` maybe you have an older version

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `lapply` function. 
I dont know how is your `for loop` solution, but mine requiere using `<<-` which is not ideal so maybe you prefer to stick to a `for loop`

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(name = c("Trigger", "Smart Triggered!", "", "", "Instrument", "Beam", "Core speed", "Channel1", "Channel2", "Channel3", "Channel4", ""),
                 values = c("SWS", "", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "Demo", "5um", "2.2", "FWS", "SWS", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "x"))

df <- as.data.table(df)

df$name <- as.character(df$name)
counting <<- 1
df$name[2:nrow(df)] <- unlist(lapply(2:nrow(df), function(x){
  if((df[x,]$name=="") && (df[x-counting,]$name=="Smart Triggered!")){
    counting <<- counting + 1
    return(paste0("Smart trigger ", counting))
  }
  else{
    counting <<- 1
    return(df[x,]$name)
  }
}
))
df
```

Comment: it does the job indeed and the <<- is not really a problem right? It just means you assign a variable one environment level higher, i.e. the global env in this case instead of the local env inside the lapply