# R datatable with tidyverse: find, relocate and rename unknown nr of rows based on a condition below a cell with a certain string in it

Tags: r, datatable

related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249632/r-data-table-how-to-find-unknown-number-of-empty-cells-directly-below-a-specif), but a different structure to the issue

In some versions of the info files coming out of my lab instrument, the smart triggers are in the left column, with an empty cell to the right of it. (in the other scenario the were in the right column, and left side was empty.
I want to find the rows that are actually a smart trigger, i.e. below the cell holding keyword, string: 'Smart Triggerd!' as these triggers are recognizable by the empty cell (`df[x,y]`) next to them. The next other parameter in the tables has entries in both columns on that row. (signalling we passed the smart trigger lines)

The amount of smart triggers used by the user of the instrument can vary, but they result in a row with their name in the cell below the one holding the words 'Smart Triggered', i.e. `df[2,1]` for each trigger and an empty cell next to them.

So, compared to the other question, they are still below the target cell from where I start looking for them, which contains "Smart Triggered!", but are in the other column now.

The `tidyverse` approach seems the way to go, but in this case I need to somehow look for the empty cells below the target cell, shifted 1 column to the right
to figure out which rows we are dealing with, then shift the left column value (the trigger names) to the empty spot on the right, and finally fill the cell on the left with numbered strings "Smart trigger 1", "Smart trigger 2", ..... n

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Trigger", "Smart Triggered!", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "Instrument", "Beam", "Core speed", "Channel1", "Channel2", "Channel3", "Channel4", ""),
                 values = c("SWS", "", "", "", "Demo", "5um", "2.2", "FWS", "SWS", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "x"))
```

[image]

looking to get this as output: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included a variation to change name of columns, this is just to give you a feel for different possibilities. Please note, in `df` I have made all columns as `characters`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(name = c("Trigger", "Smart Triggered!", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "Instrument", "Beam", "Core speed", "Channel1", "Channel2", "Channel3", "Channel4", ""),
                 values = c("SWS", "", "", "", "Demo", "5um", "2.2", "FWS", "SWS", "FLRED", "FLORANGE", "x"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
  mutate(new_name = ifelse(values == "" & name != "Smart Triggered!", NA, name)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(new_name) %>%
  split(.$new_name) %>%
  map_df(., ~.x %>% mutate(row_no = row_number(),
                           row_no = lag(row_no),
                           new_name1 = ifelse(is.na(row_no), 
                                              as.character(new_name), 
                                              paste0(as.character(new_name), "_", row_no)))) %>%
  mutate(value1 = ifelse(is.na(row_no), values, name)) %>%
  full_join(df, .) %>%
  select(new_name1, value1) %>%
  stats::setNames(., c("name", "values"))
```

Comment: OK, very nice. I was running it line by line now to better understand how it works. Replaced past0(as.character(new_name) by paste0("Smart trigger")  to get rid of capital T and the !. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wrapped the whole expression is suppressMessages() to silence the join message, as specifying join columns results in reordering of rows in alphabetical order

Comment: I ran into another obstacle, I posted a new question here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346736/r-tidyverse-way-to-change-cell-content-string-based-on-a-keyword-condition-wit