# R tidyverse way to change cell content (string) based on a keyword condition with content of another cell plus text

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm just starting to learn tidyverse approaches and currently I am looking how to solve the following problem:

in the following dataframe:

[image]

i'm looking to replace all the "sensitivity level" cells with 
the name of the channel found 1 row up, in the 2nd column, combined with the word "sensitivity"

after successfully doing so I want to run it through the other tidyverse solution to the other part of my problem that is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252006/r-datatable-with-tidyverse-find-relocate-and-rename-unknown-nr-of-rows-based-o/55252161#55252161)

this is the code to generate an exact replica of my dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Parameter = c("Trigger level (mV)", "Smart Triggered!", 
"FL Red Maximum > 9", "CytoUSB Block size", "Instrument", "Beam width", 
"Core speed", "User Comments", "Measurement date", "Measurement duration", 
"Flow rate (µL/sec)", "Channel 1", "Channel 2", "Channel 3", 
"Channel 4", "  sensitivity level", "Channel 5", "  sensitivity level", 
"Channel 6", "  sensitivity level", "Channel 7", "  sensitivity level", 
"Total number of particles", "Smart triggered number of particles", 
"Concentration (part/µL)", "Volume (µL)"), Value = c(" 10.49", 
"", "", " Auto (maxTimeOut 5s )", " EMSO II", " 5", " 2.2", " ", 
" 15-Apr-16 5:12:21 AM", " 36", " 2.06", " Trigger1", " FWS L", 
" FWS R", " SWS  TRIGGER", " 55", " FL Yellow", " 100", " FL Orange", 
" 100", " FL Red", " 100", " 1344", " 1344", " 2062.71614038604", 
" 46.7626146474752")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Parameter = ifelse(
    Parameter == "  sensitivity level",
    paste(lag(Value), "sensitivity"),
    Parameter
  ))
```

Comment: My interpretation of the question was they wanted names like "Channel 5 sensitivity", so `lag(Parameter)` instead of `lag(Value)`

Comment: thanks! this simple example helps me get a better understanding of mutate